# error applying contrasts to a factor in r

Tags: r

I get this message when trying to apply the function contrasts to a data column.

```
contrasts(ffcg2$operator) = contr.sum(5)
#Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0,  : 
#  contrasts apply only to factors
```

However it is already a factor as shown here

```
operator <- na.omit(mydata$operator)
operator <- factor(ffcg2$operator)
is.factor(operator)
#[1] TRUE
```

It is a column with 5 levels labeled 1,2,3,4 and 5.
I have tried to omit any n/a values as shown above.
Not sure what to do now is any help available?

Comment: You switch from `mydata$operator` to `ffcg2$operator` in your code. Are you sure you're using the variable you meant to use? I can't replicate the error if your data is as described.